# C++ - CreateProcess failed code 2

Tags: c++, winapi, process, exe

I am trying to use the [CreateProcess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) function in order to launch an .exe application that is in a folder in my root directory (the directory where my VS solution is). Seems simple right? It probably is but I can't for the life of me notice what I have done wrong. Every time I try to launch the .exe I get the error message "CreateProcess failed code 2" which means that the .exe file I am trying to launch cant be found.

My code:

```
void HavNetProfiler::LaunchClumsy()
{
  STARTUPINFO si;
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

  ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
  si.cb = sizeof(si);
  ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

  // Start the child process. 
  if (!CreateProcess((LPCTSTR)"Clumsy\\clumsy.exe",   // No module name (use command line)
    NULL,        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    )
  {
    printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    return;
  }

  // Wait until child process exits.
  WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

  // Close process and thread handles. 
  CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

Am I using this function wrong? Have I misunderstood how it works or have I simply missed some minor detail? I am calling the function `LaunchClumsy()` in a file that is placed in a different folder (that folder exists in the root folder just like the "Clumsy" folder though). Would that make a difference?

Thanks!

Comment: Missing `winapi` tag

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Are you talking about `#include "windows.h"` or what is a winapi tag?

Comment: @amritanshu The parent.exe is indeed in the root folder (where the folder "Clumsy" is placed).

Comment: `(LPCTSTR)` cast is a bug. Using a relative path name is the other bug.

Comment: `(LPCTSTR)"Clumsy\\clumsy.exe"` You lied to the compiler, and that never ends well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 immediate bugs in the code:

1. The `LPCTSTR` cast is wrong. If your code does not compile without that cast, you have passed an argument with the wrong character encoding. Change it to `L"Clumsy\\clumsy.exe"` to explicitly pass a wide-character string.
2. Using a relative path is very likely to fail. The system searches starting from the current working directory. That is a process-wide property, that can be altered by any thread, at any time. Use an absolute path instead.

Comment: _Change it to L"Clumsy\\clumsy.exe"_ ... and call `CreateProcessW`

Comment: @IInspectable Changing it from `(LPCTSTR)"Clumsy\\clumsy.exe"` to `TEXT("Absolute path here")`. Made it work for me. But the problem is that I would rather want to avoid using an absolute path if I can since I want this to work on all computers regardless of where you put the root folder. Got any ideas?

Comment: @zett42: Calling the Unicode version of the API explicitly is what I would prefer. It's not strictly required to solve the issue, though.

Comment: @Schytheron: A fully qualified pathname does not imply, that you have to pass a compile-time constant. If you want the path relative to a known location, determine that known location at run-time, and prepend it to your relative path. Besides, using the `TEXT()` or `_T()` macros is discouraged. It is a candidate for future failure.

Comment: @Schytheron: It solves the issue of a future reader of your code not knowing, what you intended to do. As written currently, it is unclear whether you intended to call the ANSI version or the Unicode version.

Comment: @IInspectable Hmm, I readded the relative path ("Clumsy\\clumsy.exe") and it suddenly worked. Thats strange... oh well, as long as it works now. Btw why is using `TEXT()` discouraged? What sort of problems does it cause? I tried changing it to `L"Clumsy\\clumsy.exe"` but it just underlines the string, implying I made a syntax error. Why?

Comment: @Schytheron: The generic-text mappings were relevant at a time, when developers had to support both Win95 and Windows NT. They aren't today. Windows uses Unicode (UTF-16) throughout, and you should explicitly call the Unicode versions of APIs where available (e.g. `CreateProcessW`). Using the ANSI versions introduces conversion overhead, arbitrary string length restrictions, and inability to represent strings containing characters from different code pages. IntelliSense sometimes gets confused. Ignore the squiggles, as long as the compiler is happy with the input. And don't use C-style casts.